# Compiling a single test in gtk+

Tags: c, compilation, gtk, workflow, configure

I am modifying a GTK+ widget, and as I go I am building it and running one of the tests under `tests`. Just doing `make -j<N>` is pretty slow as it also compiles and links many example applications and all the other tests, which I don't care about, when the actual compilation of what I need would otherwise be fast.

Is there a way to configure to build just one test and its dependencies, and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

The list of test programs is contained by the `TEST_PROGS` make variable. You can try to forcibly set it to a specific program, e.g.:

```
make check TEST_PROGS=treeview
```